# Comparing datetime with datepicker

Tags: c#

```
   var upit = (from c in baza.Dnevnik_rada
                        where c.ID_smjena.ToString()==cmbOdabirSmjene.Text 
                        &&  c.Datum.ToString()==(dtpOdabirDatuma.Text +" 0:00:00" ) 
                        select c.ID_radnik);

            MessageBox.Show(upit.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
```

Hi, can u please help me, the first condition works but the second dont. is that the right way to compare datetime ? when i write both of that datetime in meassageBox, i can see that they are equal and i cant understand why it doesn't work? returns 0.

Comment: compare them as datetimes, not as strings

Answer (score -1):

From MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/).

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
// The example displays the following output:
//    8/1/2009 12:00:00 AM is earlier than 8/1/2009 12:00:00 PM
```